# Simple request returning error code ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS on a specific URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

#### Summary

The URL `https://www.eponuda.com/graficke-kartice-cene/gigabyte-radeon-rx-6900-xt-16gb-gddr6-2‎56-bit-gv-r69xtgaming-oc-16gd-graficka-kartica-cena-579068` returns error below, but other URLS return expected HTML body, like for example `https://www.eponuda.com/graficke-kartice-cene/asus-geforce-dual-gaming-rtx-3060-12gb-ddr6-192bit-dual-rtx3060-12g-graficka-kartica-cena-609076`. I am clueless as to what causes the issue.

#### Code

```js
const options = {
    url: 'https://www.eponuda.com/graficke-kartice-cene/gigabyte-radeon-rx-6900-xt-16gb-gddr6-2‎56-bit-gv-r69xtgaming-oc-16gd-graficka-kartica-cena-579068',
    method: 'GET'
};

request(options, (error, response, body) => {
  console.error('error:', error); 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
  console.log('body:', body); 
});
```

#### Console

`TypeError [ERR_UNESCAPED_CHARACTERS]: Request path contains unescaped characters`

#### Environment

| software | version |
| --- | --- |
| request | 2.88.2 |
| node | 14.15.5 |
| npm | 6.14.11 |
| Operating System | Windows 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try encoding the url like this

```
url: encodeURI('https://www.eponuda.com/graficke-kartice-cene/gigabyte-radeon-rx-6900-xt-16gb-gddr6-2‎56-bit-gv-r69xtgaming-oc-16gd-graficka-kartica-cena-579068')
```

Comment: That solved the issue! Thank you very much!